# How to add add unique instance to table column?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Please help me. How can i add unique instance Autocomplete to Ant Table column?

```
{
        title: 'uuid',
        key: 'uuid',
        dataIndex: 'uuid',
        render: (text, record) => {

            return <AutoComplete value={valueAutocomplete}
                                 options={optionsAutocomplete}
                                 style={{
                                     width: 200,
                                 }}
                                 onSelect={onSelectAutocomplete}
                                 onSearch={onSearchAutocomplete}
                                 onChange={onChangeAutocomplete}/>
        }
    }
```

I add Autocomplete but if I use anyone, all set the same value.